# Trying to use private composer package on Bitbucket with dependencies

Tags: dependencies, composer-php

This is how my projects look like:

MyPackage:

```
{
    "name":             "my-enterprise/my-package",
    "description":      "my desc", 
    "license":          "proprietary",    
    "authors": [
        {
            "name":         "MySelf",
            "email":        "my@mail.com",
            "homepage":     "http://www.mywebsite.com",
            "role":         "Developer"
        }
    ],    
    "require": {
        "illuminate/support": "4.1.*@dev",
        "composer/composer": "1.0.*@dev"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [            
            "src"
        ]
    },
    "target-dir": "src",
}
```

My Project:

```
...laravel stuff (is a laravel 4 project)...

"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
    "rodamoto/visual-fox-connect": "dev-master"
},
"repositories": [
{
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://readonlyuser:withpassword@bitbucket.org/myBitBucketPackage.git"
    }
],
"minimum-stability": "stable"

...more laravel stuff...
```

The thing is, that MyPackage gets installed in my project while i don't require "composer/composer". If i include composer on MyPackage i got the message: 
    MyEnterprise/MyPackage requires composer/composer "1.0.*@dev" -> no matching found

I even tried adding the composer repo to my composer.json but it's not working.

Any help?

I need composer so i can use post/install && post/update scripts.

Thank you

Comment: Can you validate your MyPackage-composer.json. It is currently invalid in the line that requires Composer.

Comment: Thank you. You were right. It's validated now but still not working. Can i tell composer where a require package is? I mean, specify the repo for composer/composer or something like that.